# Can't connect via SSH and publickey and user B (user A can)

Tags: ssh, login

**SOLVED.** It was the group writable bit on `user_B` s home directory, that tricked me.

I'm running out of ideas on this one. Every hint would be highly appreciated.

Consider this setup:

- A server `S` running Ubuntu, users `boldewyn`, `user_A` and `user_B`
- Two laptops `A` and `B`, each with a local user `boldewyn` (has an `id_rsa` key to log in `S`) and a second key `id_rsa_A` / `id_rsa_B`. All keys are stored in `/home/boldewyn/.ssh`. Both running Ubuntu.
- `user_A` and `user_B` on `S` have empty passwords, login should be possible only via publickey and SSH.

  ```
  +--------+            +-------------------+            +--------+
  | laptop |            |       server      |            | laptop |
  |   A    |            |         S         |            |   B    |
  |        |            |                   |            |        |
  +--------+    SSH     +-------------------+    SSH     +--------+
  |id_rsa_A|------------|< user_A   user_B >|------------|id_rsa_B|
  +--------+            +-------------------+            +--------+
  |id_rsa  |------------|<    boldewyn     >|------------|id_rsa  |
  +--------+            +-------------------+            +--------+
  ```

**What works:**

- Log in from any laptop as `boldewyn` (using `id_rsa` and `S:/home/boldewyn/.ssh/authorized_keys`
- Log in from laptop `A` as user `user_A` (using `id_rsa_A` and `S:/home/user_A/.ssh/authorized_keys`: `ssh -i id_rsa_A user_A@S`)

**My problem:** On laptop `B` the exactly same setup fails for `user_B`. I can't log in on `S`, because for any reason the key is not accepted and the password prompt comes (`user_B` has no password, that's no option).

**What I've checked:**

- On laptop `B`:

  - Checked the rights of `~/.ssh` and all its content
  - put public part of `id_rsa_B` in `boldewyn`s `.authorized_keys` and `ssh -i id_rsa_B boldewyn@S`: works (the key is not corrupt or so)
  - `ssh -vvv`: Well, not really helpful: Just tells me at one point, that it skips `publickey` method now. No reason given.
- On server `S`:

  - Triple-checked `user_B`s `.authorized_keys` file
  - Checked the rights of `/home/*/.ssh` and all their contents (especially compared `user_A` and `user_B`)
  - Checked that `$HOME` is set (via `sudo -u user_B -i`)
  - Checked, that all users are in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`s `AllowUsers` (and `AllowGroups`, by the way)

**Other stuff:**

The only difference I can come up with between `user_A` and `user_B` is, that I created the latter with `adduser -M` (don't create a home directory; it already existed before). However, I triple-checked, that `/home/user_B` and all relevant children are owned by `user_B` and his primary group.

Comment: Run `sshd` on S in debug mode: `sudo sshd -rdp 1234` - often helps. (`-p 1234` is the temporary port which you will SSH to.)

Comment: Did you triple-check that `/home/user_B` (as well as `/home/user_B/.ssh` and `/home/user_B/.ssh/authorized_keys`) had the proper permissions not writable except to the user, i.e., mode 755 or more restrictive?

Comment: @grawity: Thanks for the hint. I'll try that immediately today in the evening, when I have the setup available.

Comment: @Gilles: Yes, I did. In fact, I compared file by file and dir by dir the permissions set in `user_A` s case (working) with the ones for `user_B` (not working). They're exactly the same (apart from file ownership, obviously).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you triple-check that **`/home/user_B`** (as well as `/home/user_B/.ssh` and `/home/user_B/.ssh/authorized_keys`) had the proper permissions: **not writable except to the user**, i.e., mode 755 or more restrictive?

Comment: Solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be related to the way you generated those keys. I would try again. Keys are generated with ssh-keygen facility. Perhaps when one set of keys was generated a passphrase was used in the generation process. You might try just hitting the enter key when you are prompted for a passphrase. Copy the the pub portion of that key to ubuntu. Make sure you delete to offending entry in the .ssh/authorized_keys file. A second thought: if cat the pub file make sure you use a >> (append) rather than > (replace_ when you copy the pub file to the authorized_keys file. (cat id_rsa.pub >> .ssh/authorized_keys).

I am a bit surprised. I have used my methods at work, using Solaris and Cygwin, and at home on my Linux Lan comprised of Centos, Slackware, Debian, and Ubuntu. Is it possible that you private key doesn't match the public one? When you generate your keys you get a pair, the pubic one will get copied traditionally to the .ssh/authorized keys file under the home directory of the target machine. If you re-generate the keys, the new .pub file must be copied. The new private key will not pair with the old public one. I notice that you seem to have a .authorized_keys folder in the home directory. I have never tried that. I think the normal placement is in the /home/user_name/.ssh/authorized_keys folder. I have never had problems using any version of Solaris from about 6 on up, Freebsd, and various iterations and flavors of Linux. Good Luck

Alan

Comment: The keys seems to be okay: *put public part of id_rsa_B in boldewyns .authorized_keys and ssh -i id_rsa_B boldewyn@S: works (the key is not corrupt or so)*

Comment: Thanks for the try, apolinsky, but, yes, as Arjan says, I've checked the key by using it with `boldewyn`s account.